# How to apply css in angular 2 on some specific html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

How to apply css in **angular 2**. I am using **webstorm** IDE for compilation. Also facing some cache issue, again and again I have to delete browser history, also confused about images path in css, how do i implement relative paths of images in css files and how to add custom styles in css and apply them on some specific element.

Answer (score 2):

By setting **`styles`** or **`styleUrls`** metadata

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Tour of Heroes</h1>
    <hero-app-main [hero]=hero></hero-app-main>`,
  styles: ['h1 { font-weight: normal; }']
})
```

`OR`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-app',
  templateUrl: './home.html'
  styleUrls: ['./home..css']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your css in the component.css file so that it imports the css only for that component.